How to pass a list of parameters with $regex conditions in a Spring Data MongoDB query?
I'm having an issue with a MongoDB query through a repository, as shown below. I want to modify the query so that instead of passing parameters one by one, I can pass a list of parameters. Everything would be fine, but the conditions { $regex: ?1, $options: 'i' } need to be preserved, as shown below. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?
@Repository
public interface VehicleCharacteristicsRepository
    extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<VehicleCharacteristicsEntity, String> {

  @Query(
      value =
          """
          {
            'vehicleBrand': ?0,
            'vehicleModel': {
              $nin: [
                { $regex: ?1, $options: 'i' },
                { $regex: ?2, $options: 'i' },
                { $regex: ?3, $options: 'i' },
                { $regex: ?4, $options: 'i' }
              ]
            }
          }
          """,
      fields = "{'vehicleBrand' : 1, 'vehicleModel' : 1, 'self' : 1}")
  List<VehicleCharacteristicsEntity> findAllByVehicleBrandAndVehicleModelIsNotIn(
      String vehicleBrand,
      String firstModel,
      String secondModel,
      String thirdModel,
      String fourthModel);
}


I've tried using SPeL, but I couldn't get it to work.
